# Exists there an algorithm to determine if a graph is toroidal?

Tags: algorithms, graphs

I was hoping to determine if a particular graph was [toroidal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toroidal_graph).  My first instinct was to use [Forbidden Minors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forbidden_graph_characterization), just as I would use the [Kuratowski subgraphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kuratowski%27s_theorem) to determine if a graph was planar.  After doing some digging I discovered [The Robertson Seymour theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robertson%E2%80%93Seymour_theorem) which seems to entail that such forbidden subgraphs do exist, however according to the linked Wikipedia article, citing [this paper](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1571065305051966), the particular subgraphs are currently unknown.

This is kind of a brick wall for me.  I don't recall any other way of computing planarity that might have been abstracted up to toroidality.  What algorithms are known for computing whether a given graph is toroidal?

Comment: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/119493/toroidality-testing/247820 here are given some algorithms (including linear) to solve this.

Comment: @rus9384 If I am not mistaken [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T7iDY.png) is a graph that is Toroidal but not 1-planar.

Comment: It is 1-planar and has crossing number 1. You have rectangle divided in 4 squares. And it's diagonal vertices are connected.

Comment: @rus9384 I'm not sure I follow.  If you could add an illustration even a crude one that might be helpful.

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/aHNmS this is it's redrawing.

Comment: @rus9384 Its taken me a while but I am nearly certain that the graph you have is not isomorphic to the one I have.  I even programmatically checked with [nauty traces](http://pallini.di.uniroma1.it/).

Comment: Enumerate all vertices (from left to right, 0-9): now you see that every vertex $k$ has vertices $\{k-1, k+1, k+5\} \pmod {10}$ as it's neighbors.